# Proof that $\frac{3-x^{4}}{8x^{2}}$ is the only solution to the functional equation $f(x) + 3f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = x^{2}$

Tags: functional-equations

How can we prove that $f(x) + 3f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = x^{2}$ has only one solution and no other solution and that solution is $\frac{3-x^{4}}{8x^{2}}$.

I know that this is a linear function equation, but can't find any sources which say that all linear functional equation will have only one solution.

Comment: Do you need to find out how to arrive at this solution or is it a given and you just need to find that it is unique?

Comment: The solution is given, we just want to prove it is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in addition $g(x) + 3g(1/x) = x^2$ then $$f(x) - g(x) + 3f(1/x) - 3g(1/x) = 0.$$ Define $h = f-g$ so that
$$h(x) = -3 h(1/x).$$ Now swap $x \mapsto 1/x$ to find  $$h(1/x) = -3h(x)$$ so that $$h(x) = 9 h(x).$$ This forces $h = 0$ and thus $f=g$.

Comment: Thanks :), what about the general case of all linear functional equations, do they all have at most one solution?

Comment: Techniques I know but couldn't piece together...well done.

Comment: @AbhishekKaushik do you suppose that the functional equation $f(x) = f(x+2\pi)$ has at most one solution?

Comment: No, as all trigonometric functions will follow that. :p Thanks, I was doing equations like above repeatedly so my perception got skewed

Answer (score 1):

We always have $x \ne 0.$

From

$$(1) \quad f(x) + 3f(\frac{1}{x}) = x^{2}$$

we get

$$(2) \quad f( \frac{1}{x})+3f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}.$$

If we add $(1)$ and $(2)$ we derive

$$(3) \quad f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})= \frac{1}{4}(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}).$$

$(3) - (1)$ shows that

$$(4) \quad -2f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{4}(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})-x^2.$$

Now substitute $\frac{1}{x} \to x$ in $(4)$. Easy computations give now the desired result.

Comment: But this doesn't prove no other solution exist, or does it?

Comment: It proves that there is no other solution ! I have shown: if $f(x) + 3f(\frac{1}{x}) = x^{2}$, then $f(x)=\frac{3-x^{4}}{8x^{2}}.$

Comment: Multiplying (2) with 3 and subtracting (1) would give the result a bit more directly.